# How to group XML nodes by three levels of node value in XSLT 1?

Tags: xml, transform, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT.  I have been reading XSLT documents and other posts here.  I am stuck for a while and don't know exactly what to do next.
The original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COVERAGE>
    <FILE>
        <RUNDATE>2014-04-16</RUNDATE>
        <RUNTIME>20:11:20</RUNTIME>
        <GROUPID1>GROUP ID1</GROUPID1>
        <GROUPID2>GROUP ID2</GROUPID2>
        <USERID>ABC</USERID>
        <MODULE>
            <NAME>Module1</NAME>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>
                    <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
        </MODULE>
    </FILE>
    <FILE>
        <RUNDATE>2014-04-16</RUNDATE>
        <RUNTIME>20:12:16</RUNTIME>
        <GROUPID1>GROUP ID3</GROUPID1>
        <GROUPID2>GROUP ID4</GROUPID2>
        <USERID>BDF</USERID>
        <MODULE>
            <NAME>Module1</NAME>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>Y</OV>GOV>
                    <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>GOV>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>GOV>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
        </MODULE>
    </FILE>
    <FILE>
        <RUNDATE>2014-04-16</RUNDATE>
        <RUNTIME>20:12:16</RUNTIME>
        <GROUPID1>GROUP ID3</GROUPID1>
        <GROUPID2>GROUP ID4</GROUPID2>
        <USERID>BDF</USERID>
        <MODULE>
            <NAME>Module2</NAME>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>Y</OV>GOV>
                    <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>GOV>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
                <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
                <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
                    <OV>N</OV>GOV>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
        </MODULE>
    </FILE>
</COVERAGE>
```

What I would like first, group the EXECUTED, UNEXECUTED nodes together if MODULE/NAME, UNIT/UNITDATE, UNIT/UNITTIME, CSECT/EXTNAME are the same.

The transformed XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COVERAGE>
    <FILE>
      <MODULE>
        <NAME>Module1</NAME>
            <UNIT>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
                    <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED><EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
            <UNIT>
                <CSECT>
                    <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                    <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                </CSECT>
            </UNIT>
        </MODULE>
    </FILE>
    <FILE>
        <MODULE>
            <NAME>Module2</NAME>
                <UNIT>
                    <CSECT>
                        <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
                        <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
                        <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
                        <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    </CSECT>
                </UNIT>
                <UNIT>
                    <CSECT>
                        <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
                        <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
                        <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    </CSECT>
                </UNIT>
                <UNIT>
                    <CSECT>
                        <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
                        <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
                        <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
                        <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
                    </CSECT>
                </UNIT>
            </MODULE>
        </FILE>
    </COVERAGE>
```

This XSL is what I got after my reading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
     <xsl:key name="moduleKey" match="MODULE" use="NAME" />
    <xsl:key name="unitKey" match="UNIT" use="concat(CSECT/EXTNAME, '_', UNITDATE,'_',UNITTIME)" />

    <xsl:template match="COVERAGE">
        <COVERAGE>

            <xsl:for-each select="FILE">
            <FILE>
                <RUNDATE>
                    *
                </RUNDATE>
                <RUNTIME>
                    *
                </RUNTIME>
                <GROUPID1>
                    *
                </GROUPID1>
                <GROUPID2>
                    *
                </GROUPID2>
                <USERID>
                    *
                </USERID> 
                <xsl:for-each select="MODULE[count( . | key('moduleKey', NAME)[1]) = 1]">
                <MODULE>
                    <NAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                    </NAME>
                    <xsl:for-each select="UNIT[count( . | key('unitKey', concat(CSECT/EXTNAME, '_', UNITDATE,'_',UNITTIME))[1]) = 1]">
                        <UNIT>

                                <TYPE>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="TYPE" />
                                </TYPE>
                                <UNITDATE>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="COMPILEDATE" />
                                </UNITDATE>
                                <UNITTIME>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="COMPILETIME" />
                                </UNITTIME>
                                <CSECT>
                                <EXTNAME>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="CSECT/EXTNAME" />
                                </EXTNAME>
                                <OV>
                                    *
                                </OV>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('unitKey', concat(CSECT/EXTNAME, '_', UNITDATE,'_',UNITTIME))/CSECT/EXECUTED" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('unitKey', concat(CSECT/EXTNAME, '_', UNITDATE,'_',UNITTIME))/CSECT/UNEXECUTED" />
                            </CSECT>
                        </UNIT>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </MODULE>   
                </xsl:for-each>
                </FILE>
            </xsl:for-each>


        </COVERAGE>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this XSL cannot produce what we want.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like first, group the EXECUTED, UNEXECUTED nodes together
>   if MODULE/NAME, UNIT/UNITDATE, UNIT/UNITTIME, CSECT/EXTNAME are the
>   same.

I don't see that in your output - perhaps because it's too complex for a SO question. In any case, if that's what you want, you should use a (single) key that concatenates the four characteristics of a group.

For example, the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sect" match="CSECT" use="concat(../../NAME, '_', ../UNITDATE, '_', ../UNITTIME, '_', EXTNAME)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <COVERAGE>
        <!-- FOR EACH DISTINCT GROUP -->
        <xsl:for-each select="COVERAGE/FILE/MODULE/UNIT/CSECT[count(. | key('sect', concat(../../NAME, '_', ../UNITDATE, '_', ../UNITTIME, '_', EXTNAME))[1]) = 1]">
            <MODULE>
                <NAME><xsl:value-of select="../../NAME"/></NAME>
                <UNIT>
                    <UNITDATE><xsl:value-of select="../UNITDATE"/></UNITDATE>
                    <UNITTIME><xsl:value-of select="../UNITTIME"/></UNITTIME>
                    <CSECT>
                        <EXTNAME><xsl:value-of select="EXTNAME"/></EXTNAME>
                        <!-- GET RECORDS IN CURRENT GROUP -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('sect', concat(../../NAME, '_', ../UNITDATE, '_', ../UNITTIME, '_', EXTNAME))">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="EXECUTED | UNEXECUTED"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </CSECT>
                </UNIT>
            </MODULE>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </COVERAGE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input, will produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COVERAGE>
   <MODULE>
      <NAME>Module1</NAME>
      <UNIT>
         <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
         <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
         <CSECT>
            <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
            <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
         </CSECT>
      </UNIT>
   </MODULE>
   <MODULE>
      <NAME>Module1</NAME>
      <UNIT>
         <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
         <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
         <CSECT>
            <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
            <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
         </CSECT>
      </UNIT>
   </MODULE>
   <MODULE>
      <NAME>Module1</NAME>
      <UNIT>
         <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
         <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
         <CSECT>
            <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
            <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
         </CSECT>
      </UNIT>
   </MODULE>
   <MODULE>
      <NAME>Module2</NAME>
      <UNIT>
         <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
         <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
         <CSECT>
            <EXTNAME>UNITA</EXTNAME>
            <EXECUTED>43.1 46.1 47.1 50.1 51.1 52.1 56.1 58.1 63.1 65.1</EXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>73.1 74.1 75.1 78.1 79.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
         </CSECT>
      </UNIT>
   </MODULE>
   <MODULE>
      <NAME>Module2</NAME>
      <UNIT>
         <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
         <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
         <CSECT>
            <EXTNAME>UNITB</EXTNAME>
            <EXECUTED>32.1 36.1 37.1 38.1 44.1 50.1 56.1 57.1 58.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>40.1</UNEXECUTED>
         </CSECT>
      </UNIT>
   </MODULE>
   <MODULE>
      <NAME>Module2</NAME>
      <UNIT>
         <UNITDATE>2014-03-14</UNITDATE>
         <UNITTIME>15:15:00</UNITTIME>
         <CSECT>
            <EXTNAME>UNITC</EXTNAME>
            <EXECUTED>32.1 34.1 35.1 38.1 39.1 43.1 44.1 51.1 52.1 53.1</EXECUTED>
            <EXECUTED>59.1 60.1</EXECUTED>
            <UNEXECUTED>46.1 55.1</UNEXECUTED>
         </CSECT>
      </UNIT>
   </MODULE>
</COVERAGE>
```

---

### Edit:

> Each FILE node has one MODULE node, one MODULE node has multiple UNIT
>   node, each UNIT node one CSNEXT node, each CSNEXT node has many
>   EXECUTED or UNEXECUTED nodes.

Okay, but you're not telling us exactly how to group them. And it's very difficult to tell from looking at your output file - unless one wants to spend hours comparing the input to the output. Even then the answer would not be entirely clear, because **your output is most certainly wrong**: this node:

```
<UNEXECUTED>60.1 70.1</UNEXECUTED>
```

appears **four** times in your output - but only **three** times in the input!!

I am guessing you want something like the following, which will group by MODULE (i.e. by FILE/MODULE) first, then with each group by CSECT (i.e. by UNIT/CSECT):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="module" match="MODULE" use="NAME"/>
<xsl:key name="sect" match="CSECT" use="concat(../../NAME, '_', ../UNITDATE, '_', ../UNITTIME, '_', EXTNAME)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <COVERAGE>
        <!-- FOR EACH DISTINCT MODULE -->
        <xsl:for-each select="COVERAGE/FILE/MODULE[count(. | key('module', NAME)[1]) = 1]">
            <FILE>
                <MODULE>
                    <NAME><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></NAME>
                        <!-- FOR EACH DISTINCT CSECT -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="UNIT/CSECT[count(. | key('sect', concat(../../NAME, '_', ../UNITDATE, '_', ../UNITTIME, '_', EXTNAME))[1]) = 1]">
                            <UNIT>
                                <CSECT>
                                    <EXTNAME><xsl:value-of select="EXTNAME"/></EXTNAME>
                                    <!-- GET RECORDS IN CURRENT GROUP -->
                                    <xsl:for-each select="key('sect', concat(../../NAME, '_', ../UNITDATE, '_', ../UNITTIME, '_', EXTNAME))">
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="EXECUTED | UNEXECUTED"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </CSECT>
                            </UNIT>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </MODULE>
                </FILE>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </COVERAGE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  But the MODULE node is not grouped together anymore (see the original XML file).

Comment: @kelly66 I am afraid I don't know what that means. Let me suggest you (1) minimize the XML input file to show only what's necessary for this question; (2) fix the output file in a similar way (currently it's totally incomprehensible); and (3) explain in so many words what is the logic behind the requested transformation. So far all you have said is what I quoted at the beginning of my answer - and that is exactly what my suggestion does.

Comment: Sorry Michael, English is not my first Language. I modified what XML I would like to be transformed to. Easier to understand. Hope you know what I meant. Basically, XML structure is: Each FILE node has one MODULE node, one MODULE node has multiple UNIT node, each UNIT node one CSNEXT node, each CSNEXT node has many EXECUTED or UNEXECUTED nodes. Thank you for your helps, Michael!

Comment: @kelly66 See the edit to my post. -- I don't think your English is the problem here.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael, work like a charm.  My first post here, but learn a lot.  Thank you again.